# Magento Onepage Checkout not Updating

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to change the checkout page, I've read tons of post about how to do that, but it's not working for me yet.
I changed the following files:

```
app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checko‌​ut/onepage/billing.p‌​thml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/shipping.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml

app/design/frontend/base/default/template/persistent/checkout/onepage/billing.phtml
```

After changing those files, the page does not change!

How is that possible? Am I modifying the wrong files?

Thanks

Comment: If wanted to change the look and feel of the page than you can go with magento one step check(IWD) or if want to change the Magento Checkout than you can check from where your files are coming by enabling template hint.

Comment: Thanks! This is very usefull, I was using the wrong files.